# How to move multiple vertices like subdivide?

Tags: vertices

What I want to do is to move multiple vertices(upper picture) along the edges and all the other vertices appropriately like subdivide create new vertices(lower pictures). I hope I can move all the vertices along the lines at once where subdivide create vertices if you select more "Number of Cuts" in Subdivide submenu.

In short,
I want to Move vertices along the line between inner and outter vertices(upper picture) like subdivde creates vertices along the line. Lower picture is a sample of "subdivde" between inner and outter vertices

[image: Vertices to move]

[image: Subdivided(Number of Cuts = 1) vertices]

P.S.:curved shape
[image: curved shape]

Comment: This isn't clear. The vertices on the inner arc are connected to 2 or 3 radial edges each .. which edges do you want the vertices to move along? Or do you just want to scale the inner arc outwards all together, until it lies where the subdivision line is, in the second illustration?

Comment: Yes, Robin. inner arc vertices are connected to 2 or 3 edges each. But when I use subdivide, they know exactly which line to use, because I select the outter arc vertices. I want to know if I can move all the inner arc vertices along the lines between inner and outter arc vertices just like subdivide knows which lines to create there new vertices at once.

Comment: If you get such an unexpected result, make sure you apply the scale of your object in object mode. Also, I am not sure how well offset edges work with tris, so try it with quad geometry.

Comment: Thank you dimitarsp. it works perfectly after I scaled up and down again back to original. using "Follow Face" option checked.

Comment: Cheers, and happy to help. If you are happy with the answer below, you should mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move vertices precisely along edge normals, you can use an addon called **[Offset edges](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges)**.

## Installation

Once you download the addon, go to user preferences, install addon from file, and select the downloaded file. Then make sure to tick the chckemark button to enable the addon, and save user preferences.

[image]

## Usage

Once you have it loaded, in edit mode, in the left-hand toolbar, there is a new sub-tab called offset edges. There are three commands - offset, extrude, and move. In your case, you would select the move command, after which you can specify the width.

[image]

*A sidenote - it's best to model in quads whenever you can in order to be able to subdivide your geometry efficiently with loop cuts.*